# How do I write a multivariate function?

Tags: function-construction

I want to pass input arguments to a function

In python I do,

```
def solution3d(a, b, c, d):
```

I looked at the documentation here

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/VariablesAndFunctions.html

but it's still unclear to me.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: If `solution3d` has been defined, you write `solution3d[a, b, c, d]` to pass `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` to it, to answer the question you asked.  But maybe you are asking how to define `solution3d`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you. Yes, you are right. I have a bunch of lines that have to be included inside the function. I assume `solution3d[a, b, c, d]` is to call the function after it is defined. I would like to know how to define the function

Comment: maybe `solution3d = Function[{a,b,c,d}, bunchOfLines]`?

Comment: Another way is `def f(*a):` , in mma: `f[a___]:=`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to find the information you are seeking. Bring up the Document Center (Mathematica help) window. Type "define a function" in the search field and click on the maginifing glass icon on its right. You will see

[image: and c]

or something similar depending on what OS you are running.

Click on the 2nd hit "Defining variables and functions". This will bring up

[image: help]

Lower down on this screen you see

[image: tutorial]

Click on the item that I drawn a red box around. You will now see

[image: help]

This should give a solid introduction to writing function definitions.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll want to check out https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndPrograms.html

In the notation you gave, you might write

```
solution3d[a_, b_, c_, d_] := doSomeStuff
```

If you want to do multiple things, you might write

```
  solution3d[a_, b_, c_, d_] := (x = a + b; y = c + d; {x , y})
```

The semi-colons are used to create compound expressions. The underscore after the arguments is a pattern matching symbol. Since we don’t provide any further information on what kind of patter to match to, Mathematica will match any object that comes in the first argument position and call it `a`.

To call your function, you would write

```
solution3d[8.7, 2.9, 3, 45]
```